# Solana CPI (runtime) invoke fails when creating a new account by system_instruction::create_account (on-chain program with anchor framework)

Tags: typescript, rust, blockchain, solana, anchor-solana

I am trying to create a simple program that lets users mint SPL tokens.
This program is bootstrapped by Anchor. Unfortunately, It failed on very first step creating a PDA account by CPI. Please see the detailed info below:

**----Processors------**

I tried to simplify the on-chain program's processor to create a simple PDA account using Solana system program. The processor has only one CPI.

**----Instructions-----**

I also tried to simplify the instruction by only inputting 4 accounts(See the screenshot or my code attached herewith):
In typescript test code, it is also pretty simple.
I just derive a PDA and then pass this PDA and the rest 3 accounts into the instruction. (two constraints 1. Assign a signer 2. Set mut for PDA account)

**-----Error-----**

But I still get the error

```
Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: An account required by the instruction is missing 
    Program 6KA5onmgQN7gsBZ5whPCTVL4EQcRob6vw7TYYNvik8xb invoke [1]
    Program log: Instruction: Mintnft
    Program log: First line in MintNFT processor
    Instruction references an unknown account 11111111111111111111111111111111
    Program 6KA5onmgQN7gsBZ5whPCTVL4EQcRob6vw7TYYNvik8xb consumed 15319 of 200000 compute units
    Program 6KA5onmgQN7gsBZ5whPCTVL4EQcRob6vw7TYYNvik8xb failed: An account required by the instruction is missing
    1) is minted


  2 passing (2s)
  1 failing

  1) anchor_programs
       is minted:
     Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: An account required by the instruction is missing
      at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:3961:13)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
      at Connection.sendRawTransaction (node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:3918:20)
      at sendAndConfirmRawTransaction (node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/util/send-and-confirm-raw-transaction.ts:27:21)
      at Provider.send (node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/provider.ts:118:18)
      at Object.rpc [as mintnft] (node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/program/namespace/rpc.ts:25:23)
```

It seems that I did not pass the correct accounts into the invoke body, but I have spent like a whole day checking but still not sure if there are any other missing accounts ( or AccountInfo).
It will be super appreciated if anyone can give me a hint.
You can see the summary of my code attached in a screenshot format.

**.src/lib.rs**

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use anchor_spl::token::Mint;
use solana_program::program::invoke;
use solana_program::system_instruction;


declare_id!("ArT6Hwus2hMwmNeNeJ2zGcQnvZsbrhz8vTbBdq35AdgG");

#[program]
pub mod anchor_programs {
    use super::*;
    pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>, price: u64) -> ProgramResult {
        ctx.accounts.nft_creator.price = price;
        ctx.accounts.nft_creator.collection = vec![];
        
        Ok(())
    }    
    pub fn mintnft(ctx: Context<MintNFT>) -> ProgramResult {
        msg!("First line in MintNFT processor");
        let (mint_pda, _bump) = Pubkey::find_program_address(           // Calc PDA address from passed in nft_creater_program_id
            &[b"nft_creator"], 
            &ctx.accounts.nft_creater_program.key()
        );
        if mint_pda != ctx.accounts.mint_pda_acc.key()  {                         // Confirm if passed in PDA address is the same
            return Err(ProgramError::Custom(123))
        }
        let create_acc_ix = system_instruction::create_account(        // Try create account using system_instruction
            &ctx.accounts.minter.key(),
            &ctx.accounts.mint_pda_acc.key(),
            ctx.accounts.rent.minimum_balance(Mint::LEN),
            Mint::LEN as u64,
            &spl_token::ID,
        );
        invoke(&create_acc_ix, &[                          // Use invoke to call cross program invocation
            ctx.accounts.minter.clone(),
            ctx.accounts.mint_pda_acc.clone(),
        ])?;        
        Ok(())
    }
    
}
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    #[account(init, payer=initializer, space=500)] 
    pub nft_creator: Account<'info, NftCreator>,
    #[account(mut, signer)]
    pub initializer: AccountInfo<'info>,
    pub system_program: AccountInfo<'info>,
    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>
}
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct MintNFT<'info> {
    #[account(mut, signer)]
    pub minter: AccountInfo<'info>,
    pub nft_creater_program: AccountInfo<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub mint_pda_acc: AccountInfo<'info>,
    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>
}
#[account]
pub struct NftCreator {
    collection: Vec<Pubkey>,
    price: u64
}
```

./tests/anchor_programs.ts

```
...

  it('is minted', async () => {
    let [mint_pda, _bump] = await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress(               // Use findProgram Address to generate PDA
        [Buffer.from(anchor.utils.bytes.utf8.encode("nft_creator"))],
        program.programId
    )


    const tx = await program.rpc.mintnft({                                                // Call program mintnft instruction
        accounts: {                                                                       /**@ACCOUNTS */
            // tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
            minter: initializerMainAccount.publicKey,                                       // 1. minter as the initializer
            // nftCreater: nftCreatorAcc.publicKey,
            nftCreaterProgram: program.programId,                                           // 2. this program id
            mintPdaAcc: mint_pda,                                                           // 3. The mint_pda just generated
            // mintPdaAcc: mint_pda.publicKey,
            rent: anchor.web3.SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY,                                           // 4. sysVar 
        },
        signers: [initializerMainAccount]
    });
    console.log("Your transaction signature", tx);    
  });
});
```

Or refer to the full anchor project code in the [github repo](https://github.com/happyeric77/blockchain_solana_dapp_boilerplate/tree/008.Anchor_Fix_CPI/anchor_programs)

Comment: Please add the code and your comments as text. The text is very small in the image and it can not be read without zooming in. Even then the text is a bit blurry and it can not be easily copied/referenced when writing a reply.

Comment: @Locke I am sorry for that, Let me update it in text format. it is also available on the [repo herewith](https://github.com/happyeric77/blockchain_solana_dapp_boilerplate/tree/008.Anchor_Fix_CPI/anchor_programs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized the issue:

1. I did not pass the system_program into instruction.

```
pub system_program: Program<'info, System>
```

2. Need to use invoke_signed to also let pda to sign

```
invoke_signed(                                                            
            &create_acc_ix,                                             
            &[                          
                self.minter.clone(),
                self.mint_pda_acc.clone(),
            ],
            &[&[ &mint_seed.as_ref(), &[*bump_seed] ]]
        )?;
```